# A dependency specification must be a string or a mapping

Tags: flutter

Error on line 32, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency specification must be a string or a mapping.
   ╷

```
32 │ ┌     - assets/
33 │ └ 
   ╵
```

pub get failed (65;    ╵)

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is I had the assets folder in the wrong location. It should not be under dependencies.

In addition, you must add 2 spaces before "assets", as shown in the picture:

[image]